# How to preload or lazyload images in a UITableView on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm having a problem when scrolling down and up a tableView on iPhone it gets kind of stuck while loading the images i need a method to preload the images so the scroll can be fluid or load the images 'till the scroll event stops...

any help on this?

Comment: Nowadays you'd use [`UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching). If you google demos/examples for this protocol, you should get good links.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this article](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/downloading-images-for-table-without.html) very helpful. It provides a very detailed example for lazy loading of images in the main runloop.

Comment: link broken not resolving

Answer (score 2):

[Lazy Table Images Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) included in iPhone Developer Resources. Check out [Photo Locations Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/PhotoLocations/Introduction/Intro.html) as well. It uses Core Data and "lazy loading" techniques if your image files are stored on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Well, generally speaking, preloading images for table view is a bad idea. Think of a following situation: you have 100 cells, each containing one image. That means you'll have to load 100 images before showing the table, which will have a serious impact on avaliable memory.

The "loading effect" you're talking about can be caused by two things: 
a) as you have said, the problem with loading images. If so, do it in another thread, and pass the image to main thread when it loads 
b) You're using images that are bigger or smaller than the given size. This will result in resizing the image when it appears on screen, causing the ugly stop-effect - the solution is to draw images in size which is exactly the same as their size.

Chope this was helpful, Paul

Comment: This assumes that the prefetch of images (a) will retrieve all images; and (b) you'd do it synchronously. So, while I agree that that particular straw man approach is silly, it seems perfectly logical to me to want to asynchronously prefetch images for the next few rows of a table, so that as the user scrolls, the images for these cells are already ready and waiting.

Comment: @Rob this is exactly what I'm trying to do.  Right now each image is loaded in delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. To accomplish this, should this method load images for current item & next 3? I could cache images so there wouldn't be a performance hit. Or every 4th cell I can load images for proceeding 3 items.

Comment: @AnonProgrammer - Current iOS versions have the concept of prefetching (google tutorials for [`UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching); it's too much for me to try to outline here in comments). But you simply don't need to write your own prefetching code any more; Apple has gotten pretty smart in providing the mechanisms for you to do this. It still takes a little work, but gets you out of "gee, how many cells should I prefetch and when should I do that."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about images, but with text I have downloaded JSON files when the view loads, parsed into an array and then loaded the tableview with that array.